# Validate and show validation message one by one

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2.2

I have a page with 3 input fields with required attribute on each of them. If I click submit without entering any values in them, I get 3 messages on my page all at once. Is it possible to check for the fields in sequence and display messages accordingly?

Comment: I removed the second question from your question. You should ask the second question in its own question. Do not put multiple questions in one question. Just ask one question per question. Does it make sense? :)

Comment: @BalusC Done. Any suggestions for this question ?